# Opencpu/rstudio terminated soon after launch

Tags: r, docker, opencpu

I have succesfully luanched the official opencpu/rstudio docker image in Windows.
However, soon after the launch (~1 mins) it will encounter a SIGWINCH error.
During this period I did not do anything to the launched instance.

See below the full history.

```
PS C:\Users\user> docker run -t -p 80:80 -p 8004:8004 opencpu/rstudio
 * Starting periodic command scheduler cron                                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
TTY detected. Printing informational message about logging configuration. Logging configuration loaded from '/etc/rstudio/logging.conf'. Logging to '/var/log/rstudio/rstudio-server/rserver.log'.
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Feb 21 17:26:49.141301 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 25] AH01909: 172.17.0.3:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Feb 21 17:26:49.149682 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 25] AH01909: 172.17.0.3:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Feb 21 17:26:49.149814 2024] [core:warn] [pid 25] AH00098: pid file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Feb 21 17:26:49.153534 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_R/1.2.9 R/4.1.2 OpenSSL/3.0.2 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.8.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 21 17:26:49.153565 2024] [core:notice] [pid 25] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
Using locale:Using locale:  en_US.UTF-8en_US.UTF-8

Using locale: en_US.UTF-8
Using locale: en_US.UTF-8
Using locale: en_US.UTF-8
AppArmor not available. Running OpenCPU without security profile but with rlimits.
AppArmor not available. Running OpenCPU without security profile but with rlimits.
AppArmor not available. Running OpenCPU without security profile but with rlimits.
AppArmor not available. Running OpenCPU without security profile but with rlimits.
AppArmor not available. Running OpenCPU without security profile but with rlimits.
Loading config from /usr/lib/opencpu/library/opencpu/config/defaults.conf
Loading config from /usr/lib/opencpu/library/opencpu/config/defaults.conf
Loading config from /usr/lib/opencpu/library/opencpu/config/defaults.conf
Loading config from /usr/lib/opencpu/library/opencpu/config/defaults.conf
Loading config from /usr/lib/opencpu/library/opencpu/config/defaults.conf
Loading config from /etc/opencpu/server.conf
Loading config from /etc/opencpu/server.conf
Loading config from /etc/opencpu/server.conf
Loading config from /etc/opencpu/server.conf
Loading config from /etc/opencpu/server.conf
OpenCPU cloud server ready.
OpenCPU cloud server ready.
OpenCPU cloud server ready.
OpenCPU cloud server ready.
OpenCPU cloud server ready.
[Wed Feb 21 17:27:40.950533 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
Terminated
```

This behavior is reapeatable, though the time to encounter the error various.

Comment: Perhaps related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49181052/3358272

Comment: I was looking at the post, it is a different problem. But it gave me some ideas to improve.

Comment: I added -d tag to the docker run command and enforced it to run in the background. It seems much better now. I imagine it is related to me minimizing the window...though not sure...

Comment: that sounds reasonable, good luck!